# How to join a static string and a dynamic property to pass to a helper?

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

How can I join a static string and a dynamic property to pass to a helper?

The following does not work:

```
{{svg 'icon-' model.prop1}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong approach. Either compute the final name of your icon in the controller or view, or create a new property in your model called icon e.g.

```
DS.Model.extend({
   icon: function() {
     return 'icon-' + this.get('prop1').toLowerCase();
   }.property('prop1');
  ....
```

controller/view:

```
   icon: function() {
     return 'icon-' + this.get('model.prop1').toLowerCase();
   }.property('model.prop1');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a custom helper that concatenation two values then use it as a subexpression, e.g. 'concat'

```
{{svg (concat 'icon-' model.prop1)}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of the concat helper?

Comment: Ok I was able to make it work. However, I cannot call toLowerCase on `model.pro1`, why `{{ model.prop1.toLowerCase() }}` does not work?

Comment: You can't call function in templates

Comment: oh so I have to create another helper for toLowerCase?

Comment: Ok I created a toLowerCase helper, it seems to work but it doesn't if I nest it `{{svg (concat 'icon-' (toLowerCase model.prop1))}}`
If I have only `{{concat 'icon-' (toLowerCase model.pro1)}}`, it works.